# bootstrap -table hide all rows except the clicked row

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var $table = $('#table');
$table.on('expand-row.bs.table', function (e, index, row, $detail) {
    $detail.html('Carregando os dados...');
});
```

**I would like to capture all the rows except the clicked row , and close them.**

Comment: No offense, but please ask your question in english.

Comment: «If you're not comfortable writing in English, ask a friend to proof-read it for you.» [Reference from Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Define what you mean by "close them", please. Hide them ?

Comment: Exactly close the items that were not clicked, hiding them. Sorry, 
I do not know English. Translator use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that `expand-row` is a class...
I also assume that the actual `display` value of your rows is `table-row`...
But it may be `inline` too.

Try this:

```
var $table = $('#table');
$table.on("click", '.expand-row.bs.table', function (e, index, row, $detail) {

    $('.expand-row.bs.table').each(function(){  // iterates all rows.
        $(this).css({"display":"none"});        // Here, "this" is row element.
    });

    $(this).css({"display":"table-row"});   // Here, "this" is the clicked element.

    $detail.html('Loading data ...');
});
```